# How to start launcher activity from another activity?

Tags: java, android

I created one app with two activities when I run app It opens first launcher activity In this activity I added `textView`on clicking this `textView`second activity is opened,
At the second activity again I added one textView on clicking that textView I expected to launch my first activity(Launcer activity) but this doesn't happens? Why? My Manifest file is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.adbs.abs.dhanagarmaza" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginRegi"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Register"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.adbs.abs.REGISTER" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My LoginRegi(Second activity java file 'DEFAULT activity')

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle registerBundle) {
        super.onCreate(registerBundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);

        // If user wants to login then on click "Login Me" textView open activity(LoginRegi.xml)
        loginMe = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvLoginMe);
        loginMe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent openLoginRegi = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
                startActivity(openLoginRegi);
            }
        });
    }
```

and LoginRegi.java (First activity 'LAUNCHER activity')

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_regi);

        // On click signup textView => Open activity (register.xml)
        signUp = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvSignUp);
        signUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent openRegister = new Intent("com.adbs.abs.REGISTER");
                startActivity(openRegister);
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: In normal way. by startActivity(Intent Obj);

Comment: put your code for second actvity textview clicklistener

Comment: use-->   Intent openLoginRegi = new Intent(this,LoginRegi.class);  startActivity(openLoginRegi ); and Intent openRegister = new Intent(this,Register.class);startActivity(openRegister );

Comment: check above comment your are calling activity name instaed of intent in your start activity

Comment: After adding code mentioned by you I'm getting error : Cannot resolve constructor Intent ('Anonymous' android.view.View.OnClicklistner,java.lang.Class<com.adbs.abs.Myapp.Register)

Comment: check my edited code in answer given below i have edited your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Activity 1:-

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView tvOne;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tvOne=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvOne);

        tvOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }


}
```

Activity 2:-

```
public class Main2Activity extends Activity {

    TextView tvTwo;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        tvTwo=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvTwo);

        tvTwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Intent i =new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
startActivity(i);

Comment: Where should one add this? the Manifest file? And there is no MainActivity in that application.

Answer (score 0):

you can post your code so we can get exact problem because ..
by `finish();` you can get your prevous activity back either you can do it by `Intent`

Answer (score 0):

My LoginRegi(Second activity java file 'DEFAULT activity')

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle registerBundle) {
        super.onCreate(registerBundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);

        // If user wants to login then on click "Login Me" textView open activity(LoginRegi.xml)
        loginMe = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvLoginMe);
        loginMe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent openLoginRegi = new Intent(Register.this,LoginRegi.class);
                startActivity(openLoginRegi);
            }
        });
    }
```

and LoginRegi.java (First activity 'LAUNCHER activity')

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_regi);

        // On click signup textView => Open activity (register.xml)
        signUp = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvSignUp);
        signUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent openRegister = new Intent(LoginRegi.this,Register.class);
                startActivity(openRegister);
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: By adding Intent openLoginRegi = new Intent(this,LoginRegi.class); gives me error > Cannot resolve constructor

Comment: hey check my comment in your answer use that. it will solve your problem

Comment: use--> Intent openLoginRegi = new Intent(this,LoginRegi.class); startActivity(openLoginRegi ); and Intent openRegister = new Intent(this,Register.class);startActivity(openRegister );

Comment: it is giving you error because you are not passing context in intent, it is necessary use code given by me in above comment